# How to add and toggle all li of child uls to parent ul below specific clicked li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on converting nested menu to mobil... I need to add each li of dropdown right below parent li on click and toggle them.

Here is current menu markup where dropdown is visible on hover:

```
<ul class="navigation-menu">

    <li class="white-hover"><a ceid="rd-menu" class="nav-main-links" href="#">Category</a>
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="drop-holder">
                <div class="left-side-menu dividerLine">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side-menu">
                    <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
</ul>
```

Not so sure how to tackle this one. I believe I need to elaborate on something similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    $('ul.navigation-menu li').click(function(e) 
    { 
        $(this).find('li').each(function(){
            $(this).after( each child li );
        });
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS.

Comment: if you can make jsfiddle it will be better

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3x1e245b/

Comment: @user2300867 is that similar to what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/3x1e245b/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle the style (originally on hover) on click event:

CSS:

```
/* before */
ul.navigation-menu li:hover {...}
ul.navigation-menu li:hover div.drop {...}

/* after */
ul.navigation-menu li.active {...}
ul.navigation-menu li.active div.drop {...}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.white-hover').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

---

Here's the demo with a little improvement:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.white-hover').click(function(e) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
ul.navigation-menu li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

ul.navigation-menu li.active {
    display: block;
    background-color: #09b5c9;
}

ul.navigation-menu li div.drop {
    display: none;
} 

ul.navigation-menu li.active div.drop {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 387px;
} 

.drop {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 387px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    border-top:4px solid #09b5c9;
    top:46px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 4px 0 #888 !important;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.drop-holder {
    width:387px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation-menu">
    <li class="white-hover">
        <a ceid="rd-menu" class="nav-main-links" href="#">Category</a>
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="drop-holder">
                <div class="left-side-menu dividerLine">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="white-hover">
        <a ceid="rd-menu" class="nav-main-links" href="#">Category</a>
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="drop-holder">
                <div class="left-side-menu dividerLine">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="white-hover">
        <a ceid="rd-menu" class="nav-main-links" href="#">Category</a>
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="drop-holder">
                <div class="left-side-menu dividerLine">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="white-hover">
        <a ceid="rd-menu" class="nav-main-links" href="#">Category</a>
        <div class="drop">
            <div class="drop-holder">
                <div class="left-side-menu dividerLine">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="right-side-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This helped me figure it out. I was overthinking it and taking a an overcomplicated approach. Thanks for helping out!